# Regex may only allow specified characters

Tags: .net, regex

- List item

I use following Regex to validate a string ^[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*

```
    private static void ValidateActualValue(string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, (@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*")))
        {
            throw new InvalidBarcodeException(value);
        }
    }
```

The following string should be allowed             string correctBarcodeString = "1-234567890/A";
However there's still an exception thrown.

Allowed values should be:

- 1234234545689889097
- A-adf90923409/1234
- aaaaaaaAAA
- BC-9876655788
- BC-345/q3435/wqer
- ABC-/BCD
- etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character group the `-` has to be at the beginning or at the end, otherwise it has to be escaped.

So change it to

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]*"
```

Edit:

I would also suggest an anchor at the end of the regex, otherwise it will also match as long as the first part is valid.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9/-]*$"
```

if you want to avoid matching the empty string then use `+` instead of `*`. Or if you know a valid Min/Max Range for the length use `{4,20}`, if the minimum amount of characters is 4 and the maximum is 20.

Comment: this matches true for all of the above examples.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `-` character at the end of the class or escape it.

`[a-zA-Z0-9/-]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9\-/]`

Answer (score 1):

I that that you really want;

```
@"^[\w/-]+"
```

Using a + instead of a * will also cover the empty string. \w = all numbers + letters

Comment: \w matches also underscore `_`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-/]*"
```

to

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9/]*"
```

You have an extra hyphen after 9.

Comment: I think he wanted '-' to count as well.